# Animate visibility modes, GONE and VISIBLE

Tags: android, animation, visibility, slide

So im trying to animate when i set the visibility of a linearlayout with other widgets, from GONE to VISIBLE and the opposite.Im using togglebuttons to show and hide. Here's an image to show what i want to do:

[image]

I can show and hide, but im not following how can i animate the sliding correctly....:(

Heres my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- TITULO1 -->
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:orientation="horizontal" 
                android:background="#848284"
                android:padding="4px">  
                <TextView 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
                    android:text="Informação Geral" 
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="18px" 
                    android:paddingLeft="4px">
                </TextView>
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:paddingTop="2px">
                        <ToggleButton 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                            android:textOff="Expandir" 
                            android:textOn="Minimizar"
                            android:id="@+id/mostrar" 
                            android:width="80px">
                        </ToggleButton>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
            <!--LINHA SEPARADORA-->
            <View 
                android:id="@+id/View01" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:background="#B5B5B5" 
                android:layout_height="2px">
            </View>
            <!-- CONTENT INITIALLY HIDDEN (GONE) -->
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"  
                android:id="@+id/informgeral"
                android:orientation="vertical"> 
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:paddingBottom="5px" 
                    android:paddingTop="5px" 
                    android:paddingLeft="8px"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/consult_nrprocesso"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                            android:singleLine="true" 
                            android:text="@string/srch_number_proc"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/consult_nrprocessovalue"
                            android:layout_width="0px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:ellipsize="end"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/consult_tipoprocinfo"
                            android:text="Numero Atribuido ao Processo"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:ellipsize="end" 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                            android:textSize="12px"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View 
                    android:id="@+id/View01" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:background="#B5B5B5" 
                    android:layout_height="1px">
                </View>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:paddingTop="5px" 
    android:paddingBottom="5px" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="8px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/consult_tipoproc"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:singleLine="true" 
                android:text="@string/proc_type"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/consult_tipoprocvalue"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/consult_tipoprocinfo"
            android:text="Variante do Processo em causa"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="12px"/>
    </LinearLayout>     
</LinearLayout>
<View android:id="@+id/View01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:background="#B5B5B5" 
        android:layout_height="1px">
</View>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:paddingTop="5px" 
    android:paddingBottom="5px" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="8px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/consult_etapa"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:singleLine="true" 
                android:text="@string/srch_task"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/consult_etapavalue"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/consult_etapainfo"
            android:text="Etapa onde se encontra o processo"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="12px"/>
    </LinearLayout>     
</LinearLayout>
<View android:id="@+id/View01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#B5B5B5" 
        android:layout_height="1px">
</View>
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:paddingTop="5px" 
    android:paddingBottom="5px" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="8px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/consult_criadopor"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:singleLine="true" 
                android:text="@string/criado_por"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/consult_criadoporvalue"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/consult_criadoporinfo"
            android:text="Entidade responsável pela criação do Processo."
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="12px"/>
    </LinearLayout>     
</LinearLayout>
<View android:id="@+id/View01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#B5B5B5" 
        android:layout_height="1px">
</View>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout05" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:paddingTop="5px" 
    android:paddingBottom="5px" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="8px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/consult_assunto"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:singleLine="true" 
                android:text="@string/proc_subject"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/consult_assuntovalue"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/consult_assuntoinfo"
            android:text="Assunto do Processo"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="12px"/>
    </LinearLayout>     
</LinearLayout>
<View android:id="@+id/View01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#B5B5B5" 
        android:layout_height="1px">
</View>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout05" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:paddingTop="5px" 
    android:paddingBottom="5px" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="8px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/consult_datainicio"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:singleLine="true" 
                android:text="@string/srch_datebeg"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/consult_datainiciovalue"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/consult_dataincioinfo"
            android:text="Data da criação do Processo"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="12px"/>
    </LinearLayout>     
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- TITULO2 -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#848284" android:padding="4px"> 
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
        android:text="Informação Complementar" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:paddingLeft="4px" android:textSize="16px">
    </TextView>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" 
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical" 
        android:paddingTop="2px">
        <ToggleButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textOff="Expandir" 
            android:textOn="Minimizar"
            android:id="@+id/mostrar2" 
            android:width="80px">
        </ToggleButton>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<View 
    android:id="@+id/View01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#B5B5B5" 
    android:layout_height="2px">
</View>

<!-- TITULO3 -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#848284"
    android:padding="4px">  
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
        android:text="Documentos Anexados" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="18px" 
        android:paddingLeft="4px">
    </TextView>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" 
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical" 
        android:paddingTop="2px">
        <ToggleButton 

            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textOff="Expandir" 
            android:textOn="Minimizar"
            android:id="@+id/mostrar" 
            android:width="80px">
        </ToggleButton>
    </LinearLayout>     
</LinearLayout>
<!--LINHA SEPARADORA-->
<View 
    android:id="@+id/View01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#B5B5B5" 
    android:layout_height="2px">
</View>
<!-- TITULO4 -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#848284"
    android:padding="4px">  
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
        android:text="Etapas" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="18px" 
        android:paddingLeft="4px">
    </TextView>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" 
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical" 
        android:paddingTop="2px">
        <ToggleButton 

            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textOff="Expandir" 
            android:textOn="Minimizar"
            android:id="@+id/mostrar" 
            android:width="80px">
        </ToggleButton>
    </LinearLayout>     
</LinearLayout>
<!--LINHA SEPARADORA-->
<View 
    android:id="@+id/View01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#B5B5B5" 
    android:layout_height="2px">
</View>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here's the java code that calls the button event:

```
final ToggleButton bt=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.mostrar);


    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (bt.isChecked()) {

                /*TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0,
                          -findViewById(R.id.informgeral).getHeight()*2);
                           slide.setDuration(500);
                           slide.setFillAfter(true);
                           findViewById(R.id.informgeral).startAnimation(slide);*/

                findViewById(R.id.informgeral).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);;

            } else {

            /*  TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0,
                          findViewById(R.id.informgeral).getHeight());
                           slide.setDuration(500);
                           slide.setFillAfter(true);
                           findViewById(R.id.informgeral).startAnimation(slide);*/


                           //findViewById(R.id.listBut).startAnimation(slide);


                findViewById(R.id.informgeral).setVisibility(View.GONE);;


            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Holy wall of XML! O.o

Comment: Yep its probably possible to make it smaller :P

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes xd

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like [tomash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043398/animate-visibility-modes-gone-and-visible/4043450#4043450) said before: There's no easy way.

You might want to take a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519479/how-does-one-animate-layout-properties-of-viewgroups/7532815#7532815).
It explains how to realize a sliding (dimension changing) view.
In this case it was a left and right view: Left expanding, right disappearing.
It's might not do exactly what you need but with inventive spirit you can make it work ;)

Answer (score 287):

To animate layout changes, you can add the following attribute to your LinearLayout

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

and it will animate changes automatically for you.

---

For information, if  `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` is used, then custom animation via anim xml will not work.

Comment: But only from API 11 (Android 3.0)

Comment: You just saved the little world =)

Comment: Simple but saved a lot of effort. Thanks.

Comment: im using it inside recycler view and when it open (VISABLE) its work greate, and when its GONE the item below jump up before animation end. any idea?

Comment: Late on this one but use INVISIBLE instead of GONE. That might help probably. @itzhar

Comment: Any way to change the speed at which this animation occurs?

Comment: @itzhar I'm having the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: @itzhar I'm late to the party, but I think I'm having the exact same problem that you describe here. I've create a new question for that but didn't get any answer. Did you somehow solve this?

Answer (score 22):

Visibility change itself can be easy animated by overriding  setVisibility method. Look at complete code:

```
public class SimpleViewAnimator extends FrameLayout
{
    private Animation inAnimation;
    private Animation outAnimation;

    public SimpleViewAnimator(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setInAnimation(Animation inAnimation)
    {
        this.inAnimation = inAnimation;
    }

    public void setOutAnimation(Animation outAnimation)
    {
        this.outAnimation = outAnimation;
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisibility(int visibility)
    {
        if (getVisibility() != visibility)
        {
            if (visibility == VISIBLE)
            {
                if (inAnimation != null) startAnimation(inAnimation);
            }
            else if ((visibility == INVISIBLE) || (visibility == GONE))
            {
                if (outAnimation != null) startAnimation(outAnimation);
            }
        }

        super.setVisibility(visibility);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add
public SimpleViewAnimator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
}
Otherwise, this will not inflate from the layout xml!

Answer (score 18):

This is a quite old question, still comments show, that still people have problems, so here is my solution with following additional features:

- adjust the animation (speed, type, ...)
- does not need to extend any class
- in my case, animateLayoutChanges has problems in the new `CoordinatorLayout`

**Function - Example (I have this function in an utility class)**

```
public static void animateViewVisibility(final View view, final int visibility)
{
    // cancel runnning animations and remove and listeners
    view.animate().cancel();
    view.animate().setListener(null);

    // animate making view visible
    if (visibility == View.VISIBLE)
    {
        view.animate().alpha(1f).start();
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    // animate making view hidden (HIDDEN or INVISIBLE)
    else
    {
        view.animate().setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
            {
                view.setVisibility(visibility);
            }
        }).alpha(0f).start();
    }
}
```

**Adjust animation**

After calling `view.animate()` you can adjust the animation to whatever you want (set duration, set interpolator and more...). You may as well hide a view by scaling it instead of adjusting it's alpha value, just replace the `alpha(...)` with `scaleX(...)` or `scaleY(...)` in the utility method if you want that

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use an ExpandableListView, a special ListView that allows you to open and close groups.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to animate hiding/showing views. You can try method described in following answer: [How do I animate View.setVisibility(GONE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634073/how-do-i-animate-view-setvisibilitygone/3952933#3952933)

Comment: Does this assure that when you show something that is GONE it will expand and pushes everything bellow too?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the expandable list view explained in API demos to show groups

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html.

To animate the list items motion, you will have to override the getView method and apply translate animation on each list item.
The values for animation depend on the position of each list item.
This was something which i tried on a simple list view long time back.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a very easy way, but just setting `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` will not work. You need to enableTransitionType in you activity. Check this link for more info: http://www.thecodecity.com/2018/03/android-animation-on-view-visibility.html