# Android: custom a menu create

Tags: android, android-layout, menu

**I don't know which type of this menu. can anyone help me.**

[image]

I want to create menu like this screen. When i click the button then pop-up the menu like this. I don't know how to achieve this. i do not know what type of this menu. and can it run on android 2.2?

Comment: Hi There Create Custom Dialog and set the x and y positions (means set Attributes).so you can achive that one

Comment: yaa its right but what about when user click at the left button. then its open at center position.

Comment: you can also use PopUpWindow  developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: @Gautam Vasoya it's nice and also user-friendly..user can easily do deletion or cancel operation rapidly...:)

Comment: @GautamVasoya you can set the positions of dialog where that should come set x and y positions of that dialog then it should come at that button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current popup menu called QuickAction Dialog in Android. you can customize it According to you need. see following good tutorial for creating `QuickAction` View in Android:

[How to Create QuickAction Dialog in Android](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)

[Quick Actions Android](http://www.okilla.com/23/tutorial-quick-actions-android/)

Answer (score 2):

This is **Quick Action 3d**. Checkout source and example from [here](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D) :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly a custom dialog. But, yes it is still a customized view. And it is more or less called **Quick Action Dialog** in android. I would suggest you to follow the tutorials below for generating an exactly same popover (or even better) with Android. Check the screenshot also.

- http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/
- https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D

[image]

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131076/how-do-replicate-this-android-pop-up)