# Custom menu in toolbar in android.

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I want to create a menu similar to this.

[image]

Please guide me to do that. Thanks.

Comment: This is might be duplicate question kindly check this URL : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16733782/1311951

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: custom a menu create](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733564/android-custom-a-menu-create)

Comment: How to add the same in toolbar menu? I tried that tutorial. It's working inside an activity or fragment. But, not in toolbar. That's why posted here. If it's still duplicate question then please tel me. I will delete this one. 

One more thing, This is my detailed explanation of the same question. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316117/android-layer-list-not-working-properly-in-some-android-versions

No one interested to look that one. That's why posted simple one here.

Answer (score 0):

Start by following this: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html

It specifically shows adding buttons to the bar but in the same xml you can set them to show up as a menu like you want.