# How to realize stretching smoothly?

Tags: android

I have a application in my mobile phone that is UC browser.there is a function that when i click the address bar,it will stretching smoothly.when i click the cancel,it will also.

i want to do this function,I use the scale to realize,but is not so good,not fluently.

could anybody tell me how to realize it?ths

[image]

when i click the URL,it will stretching smoothly

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `animations`.
Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519479/how-does-one-animate-layout-properties-of-viewgroups/7532815#7532815) question.