# Changing visibility of a view to gone with animation

Tags: android

[image]

I have 3 textviews in a linear layout. On a button press I have to hide 2 of them, as show in figure above. Right now it suddenly flashes and doesn't look good at all. I want to have a 'collapse' effect so that it slowly goes up like its being shrinked. 
Any leads on how to do this?

I tries 'animateLayoutChanges' in XML and Tranlate animation but none of them is a smooth experience.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I think the best way is translateanimation . Try it with Java code

Comment: Tried it! Any specifics will help

Comment: cant you use an objectanimator? just make the set to gone at the end of the animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can animate your linearlayouts by adding this paramter:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

This only works from API 11/Android 3.0.
As far is i know, this is the only easy way to animate the change of visibility. If you want something more custom, i don't think there is a shorter way around.

Comment: Tried it already as I mentioned. But its not smooth, still flashes.

Comment: Have you tried it on a different device? Or with different timings? If you want more control over it, i would suggest to override setVisibility and give it a custom animation there. Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12388385/1759274

Answer (score 0):

For a "collapse" animation you could do the following animation in on click of your textview

```
TranslateAnimation collapseAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -view.getHeight());
        collapseAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            //.....

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        collapseAnim.setDuration(300);
        collapseAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(0.5f));
        //Starts Animation
        view.startAnimation(collapseAnim);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = dismissView.getLayoutParams();
    final int originalHeight = dismissView.getHeight();

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);

    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            //gone dismissView
        }
    });

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            lp.height = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            dismissView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });

    animator.start();
```