# Animation View View.setVisibily(View.VISIBLE) in Android

Tags: android, animation

I have a vertical linearLayout v1, v2.
By default v1 has visibily = GONE. I would like to show v1 with an expand animation and push down v2 at the same time (GONE -> VISIBLE).

In this link [How do I animate View.setVisibility(GONE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634073/how-do-i-animate-view-setvisibilitygone) to know the effect a view slowly disappeared (VISIBLE -> GONE), but not (GONE -> VISIBLE).

Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: Refer to [this][1] thread.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634073/how-do-i-animate-view-setvisibilitygone