# NineOldAndroids translating view doesn't change position

Tags: android, animation, nineoldandroids

I am using NineOldAndroids and using setTranslationY and setTranslationX to change the views position (after applying AnimatorProxy). Only problem is when I change the view's position the button is only visually changing its location however I still have to click the original area in order to get the button working properly (instead of the new position).

Can anyone please help me figure this out, would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the view after the animation has completed. As you said, the animation will only change where the view is being drawn.

See this answer: [NineOldAndroids, not clickable view after rotation or move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173808/nineoldandroids-not-clickable-view-after-rotation-or-move?rq=1)

Comment: Funny I had just finished looking at that post. I have been experimenting with setting LayoutParams and setFillAfter(true). Most people looking for an answer to a similar question should experiment those functions.
Thank you for the answer!