# Screen resolution assistance

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I need help with my application,

I am making an android game and i want it to appear circles or squares on random point on screen. Now the problem I am facing is that i want it to appear by using `random.nextint()`... I have already made the png pictures, and everything else but i do not know how to get the screen x and y (what i mean is the max x and y) so i can use it in my random. Also how could i make it appear and dissapear every lets say 2 second?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this to get screen size programatically

[How do I get the ScreenSize programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252067/how-do-i-get-the-screensize-programmatically-in-android)

To make views disappear use Animations, here is an example:

[How do I animate View.setVisibility(GONE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634073/how-do-i-animate-view-setvisibilitygone)