# ExpandableListView Animation while closing expanded list

Tags: java, android, animation, expandablelistview

i am trying to give animation to `ExpandableListView`. i did manage to give animation to expanding list when group is click with following code

```
               public View getChildView(final int groupPosition,
            final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            vv = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.homescreen_submenu, null);
        } else {
            vv = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
        }

        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.anim_pushin);
        vv.startAnimation(animation);
        }
```

How can I achieve when child-collapsed, I saw sum tutorial [Android Animation: Hide/Show Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070225/android-animation-hide-show-menu) but did not succeed. Can anyone tell how to make it?

and 
2) When I am scrolling while group is expanded and then if I click on 2nd group, 2 group header goes out of the screen, I can see sub menu of that.

I tried select position but didn't work.

Edit :- i also saw this http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-exapandlistview-animation.html but i want list to be display when click on group

Edit2 : i have added this code , but in this only last child is animated

```
    mainmenu.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        public boolean onGroupClick(final ExpandableListView parent,
                View v, final int groupPosition, long id) {
            if (groupPosition == 2) {
                Toast.makeText(Homescreen.this, "Group 2 clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
            if (groupPosition == 3) {
                Intent nextscreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        reminder.class);
                startActivity(nextscreen);
                finish();
                return true;
            }

            if (groupPosition == 5) {
                Toast.makeText(Homescreen.this, "Group 3 clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            } else

            if (mainmenu.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {

                vv.startAnimation(animationc);
                animationc.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        vv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                                R.color.white_trs));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mainmenu.collapseGroup(groupPosition);

                    }
                });

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to override onGroupExapnded() method properly. check inside it that whether other Groups are expanded or not using isExpanded(), if it is make it collapsed.

Comment: but how to animate public View getChildView ? i tried  if grp.isExpanded(){ list.startanimation} but in this full list get animation effect i want only child list to be animated

Comment: which type of animations you want in child item??? can u post your child xml file.

Comment: i am not able to set animation for child list when it collapse , any animation will do