# ExpandableListView Slow expanding

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How can I increase the duration of expand action in expandableListView in android

In my code when I call

```
 expList.expandGroup(gp);
```

it expands very quickly ... I want it to be expanded slowly to appear as if it is sliding

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385567/animation-for-expandablelistview) is similar to yours and therefore may be of use to you.  It seems like the right approach to take is to look at it as an animation, in which case the answer to the above question would apply; it also seems (unfortunately) that the easiest way to do it would be using a regular `ListView` and handling the expansion and animation yourself.