# Animate Group Expansion in expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am using expandable list view for my app. Everything is working correctly, but I want an animation when a group is going to expand i.e all the childs should come with an animation when a group is clicked. Does any one of you have any luck in this regard?

Comment: i've thought of a possible solution, [**here**][1] .


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20884167/878126