# Activity's animation design

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

i've found this animation, it's a launcher i've downloaded.

Is there a way i can do something similar? What do i need to reproduce this type of layout and animation's style?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: looks like `ExpandableListView`. but I don't remember if it animates expanding...

Comment: looks like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9112691/1418097) can be used to implement this

Comment: Your link is very useful. I'm checking it out.